# javascript validate date in the past

Tags: validation, date

I want to compare if a given date is in the past or future.
The given date is coming in from a string in yyyy-mm-dd format.
I tried to "even out" the today and compensating the timezone in the given date date but I am sure there must be a better way to this??

```
var today           = new Date();
console.log("TODAY: " + today); // Mon Apr 28 2014 14:46:41 GMT+0200 (CEST)
var todayYear       = today.getFullYear();
var todayMonth      = today.getMonth();
todayMonth          = parseInt(todayMonth, 10) + 1;
var todayDay        = today.getDate();
var todayFormatted  = todayYear + "-" + todayMonth + "-" + todayDay;
today               = new Date(todayFormatted);
console.log("TODAY: " + today); // Mon Apr 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
var testDate        = new Date("2014-04-28");
console.log("TEST: " + testDate); // Mon Apr 28 2014 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
testDate.setHours(00);
console.log("TEST: " + testDate);
// check if test is in the past
(testDate < today) ? console.log('test is in the past') : console.log('test is NOT in the past');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the "Unix times" mathematically:

```js
var today = new Date();
console.log(testDate.getTime() < today.getTime()
 ? 'test is in the past'
 : 'test is NOT in the past');
```